# Typing Vue3 Dynamic Components

Tags: typescript, types, vuejs3, vue-component

I can't stop my TS linter to complains about my dynamic component

```js
import CompONe from '../compONe.vue';
import CompTwo from '../compTwo .vue';


const dynamicComponent: any = computed(() => {
  return type === 'one' ? CompONe : CompTwo 
})

<component :is="dynamicComponent" />
```

What would be the type of `dynamicComponent` here?

Comment: If you remove `: any` it should automatically receive it's correct type through [inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html).  If you're having trouble with a specific error, it would be prudent to include the full error details in your question.